# Android TouchableOpacity Intermittent "error"

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

I'm having an intermittent problem with the TouchableOpacity component in react-native.

I basically click on the element, it performs the opacity animation normally, but my console.log runs randomly. In iOS works correctly.

My code:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor:'red'}} onPress={async () => {
  console.log('Button '+item.tag+' pressed.');
}}>
```

NOTE: I've tried calling this function without async.

Comment: I noticed that PanResponder is interfering with the functioning of TouchableOpacity, but I still don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

PanResponder was detecting micro movements on simple touch. In the `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder` parameter I defined the following function:

```
    panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (e, g) => {
            return Math.abs(g.dx) > 2 || Math.abs(g.dy) > 2;
        },
        ...
    });
```